# Sitecore 9 Form redirecting users to /formbuilder

Tags: sitecore-forms

We've created a multi-page form using `Sitecore Forms`. We have an intermittent issue after the user click the `Next` button to go to the next page. Sometimes the form will redirect the user to http://oursite.example.com/formbuilder?blahblahblah..

This is disruptive because it's an unstyled form with a completely white background that looks very different from our website. What's confusing is that it only  happens some of the time, and other times the form works fine.

What could be causing this redirect back to `/formbuilder`?

Comment: Do you have @Html.RenderFormStyles() and @Html.RenderFormScripts() in your layout?  It is odd that this only occurs some of the time.  You might want to check for Javascript errors in the console and confirm that all of the appropriate scripts are successfully loaded by output of the @Html.RenderFormScripts() helper.  If these scripts are not loaded correctly a full postback to /formbuilder will occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this before.  It was solved by adding `@Html.RenderFormStyles()` in the `head` section of the layout and `@Html.RenderForScripts()` before the ending `body` tag in the layout.

Comment: It should be edited to @Html.RenderFormScripts()

Answer (score 0):

It may be intermittent if you are using forms extensions. I only see this when a user encounters an error with the file upload field if I put something like content type validation on and then test by entering an invalid type. I see the white user unfriendly screen then.